# Understanding the time.Parse function in Go

Tags: c#, go, time

I am currently porting code from go to c# and came across this (simplified) piece of code.
I do know that it converts a given string `171228175744.085` using a given format `060102150405`.

The official docs only have examples using common formats like `2017-Feb-1`,  not this format (a possible timestamp?)

I do know that this will result in the time beeing `2017-12-28 17:57:44.085 +0000 UTC`, but I do not have a clue how, because I have no information what the string `171228175744.085` and layout represent. I do know that some of this information is GPS related. So, my question is: Does anyone know how to do this in c#?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    t, err := time.Parse("060102150405", "171228175744.085")
    if err == nil{
        fmt.Println(t)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The docs around [time.Format](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Format) explain what the format means.

Quoting:

```
Format returns a textual representation of the time value formatted
according to layout, which defines the format by showing how the 
reference time, defined to be

Mon Jan 2 15:04:05 -0700 MST 2006
```

The format string in your example: `060102150405` tells the time parser to look for the following:

- 06: year
- 01: month
- 02: day of the month
- 15: hour of the day
- 04: minute
- 05: second

This is a convenient way of telling the parser how it should interpret each number. If you look carefully, you'll see that numbers are not reused so when you say `06`, the parser matches it to `2006`.

In C#, you can use [datetime.ParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx). Something along the lines of:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "yyMMddhhmmss", some_provider);
```

(note: I have not tried the C# snippet above. You may need to adjust it)

Comment: Thank you for your very fast response!